# Create file if program exited successfully

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create file upon the exit of a java program (app.jar). However I want this file to be created only if the program completed successfully (returns a zero status code).

Here is my attempt:

```
trap "if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then touch /tmp/javaCompleted; fi" EXIT
java app.jar
```

`$?` is supposed to give me the status code of the last executed command, that I believe to be the status code of my java program. However I noticed that this `$?` is always set to 0, independetly of the exit status returned by java. I actually suspect that `$?` is actually the one of the trap command...

Can you please explain why this isn't working and suggest a fix?

Comment: `$?` is expanded inside double quotes before `trap` even runs. Use single quotes instead.

Comment: To clarify @chepner's comment, `false; trap "if [ $? -eq 0 ]; ... " EXIT` is equivalent to `trap 'if [ 1 -eq 0 ]; ...' EXIT`, and `true; trap "if [ $? -eq 0 ]; ..." EXIT` is equivalent to `trap 'if [ 0 -eq 0 ]; ....' EXIT`.  The `$?` is being expanded to its value at the moment the trap is defined, not when it is executed.  Using single quotes will prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `trap`:

```
java app.jar && touch /tmp/javaCompleted
```